# JSDT - Variable never read - bug or feature?

Tags: javascript, eclipse, eclipse-jsdt

In eclipse using a JavaScript project i set the never-read-variable-scanner to "error" (<kbd>Alt+w</kbd><kbd>p</kbd>, `JavaScript`->`Validator`->`Errors/Warnings`)

Now i habe the function "MyFunction"

```
function MyFunction() {
    var self = this;
    function getSelf() {
        return self;
    }
    return {
        getThis : +getSelf
    };
}
```

Everything works fine. But if i remove the `+` sign, its telling me `self` is never read.

Is it a bug or a feature and why?

Comment: I'd call it a bug. The code is essentially nonsense *with* the `+`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's maybe a BUG, try this code in other IDE and if this work, the problem is on eclipse

Comment: Id created a bug report https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=464805 this will proove your answer the best i think.